# Inequality of expectation of two random variables

Tags: real-analysis, statistics, inequality, independence, estimation

I try to understand a proof about minimax rates for an estimator class. However, one step remains unclear:

Assume to observe $N$ independent samples from a distribution $\mathcal{P}$:
$(X_i, W_i, Y_i)_{i=1}^N \sim \mathcal{P}^N $, where $X_i$ denotes the random vector of covariates for unit $i$, $W_i$ specifies whether the unit $i$ was treated or not $(0 $ or $ 1)$, and $Y_i$ is the dependent random variable. Then $Y_i$ can be written as:

$Y_i = W_i Y_i(1) + (1-W_i)Y_i(0)$, where $Y_i(0) \in \mathbb{R}$ denotes the potential outcome of unit $i$ that could be observed if $i$ were assigned to the control group, whereas $Y_i(1) \in \mathbb{R}$ is the potential outcome of $i$ under treatment.

Define now the "treatment function" $\tau(x) := \mathbb{E}[ Y(1) - Y(0) \mid X = x ]$ and assume  $\tau(x)$ to be linear, i.e. $\tau(x)=x^T\beta$, with $\beta \in \mathbb{R}^d$.

I am now interested in the following expectation:
$\mathbb{E} \Big[ (\tau(\mathcal{X}) - \hat{\tau}(\mathcal{X}))^2\Big] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ (\mathcal{X}(\beta - \hat{\beta}))^2 \Big]$, where the expectation is taken over the training data set $(X_i, W_i, Y_i)_{i=1}^N \sim \mathcal{P}^{N}$, and $\mathcal{X}$, which is distributed according to the marginal distribution of $X$ in $\mathcal{P}$.

The authors make the following claim:
$\mathbb{E} \Big[ (\tau(\mathcal{X}) - \hat{\tau}(\mathcal{X}))^2 \Big] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ (\mathcal{X}(\beta - \hat{\beta}))^2 \Big] \leq  \mathbb{E} \big[ \Vert \mathcal{X} \Vert^2 \big] \mathbb{E} \big[\Vert \beta - \hat{\beta}\Vert^2 \big]$.

My attempt to understand how they reach this inequality:

$\mathbb{E} \Big[ (\tau(\mathcal{X}) - \hat{\tau}(\mathcal{X}))^2 \Big] = \mathbb{E} \Big[ (\mathcal{X}(\beta - \hat{\beta}))^2 \Big] \overset{Cauchy-Schwarz}{\leq} \mathbb{E} \Big[ \Vert \mathcal{X} \Vert^2 \Vert \beta - \hat{\beta}\Vert^2 \Big] \\
 \overset{\perp} {=} \mathbb{E} \big[ \Vert \mathcal{X} \Vert^2 \big] \mathbb{E} \big[\Vert \beta - \hat{\beta}\Vert^2 \big]$ ,

where $\perp$ means independence of the random variables. However, there is no reason for $\mathcal{X}$ and $(\beta - \hat{\beta})$ (which relies on the training data set) to be independent in my opinion. Which other inequality could be used to reach the claim made by the authors?

Thanks a lot!

Comment: I'm not sure if it will help but generally in statistics the covariates are not considered random but fixed with only the distribution of y and the sampling distribution of beta's being random. If that is the case then the sampling distribution of beta will always be independent of the covariates as the covariates will act as constants. That's my heuristic thoughts anyway. Not always, there is random effects models.

Comment: Thanks, I think you are right! I found a side node, where the authors argue: "The expectation is here taken over $\hat{\tau}$ and $\mathcal{X} \sim \Lambda$ (the marginal distribution of $\mathcal{X}$ in $\mathcal{P}$), where $\mathcal{X}$ is independent of $\hat{\tau}$." This independence can only be justified, when the covariates are considered fixed, right? So the whole "randomness" of $(\beta-\hat{\beta})$ comes from the fact that the training data set $(X_i, W_i, Y_i)_{i=1}^N$ is sampled from the underlying distribution?

Comment: Actually I have been thinking about it more and I might have been wrong. I'm sorry about that. The reason the difference in the betas is independent of X is because that distribution never relies on X. Invoking the CLT, it's distribution will be Normal(0, sigma^2/n) which doesn't rely on X. Sorry I was not correct in my original answer. Good luck!

Comment: Thank you a lot !